# Android: OnClickListener throws NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have two Activities. In my main Activity I am creating an intent to start the other one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Settings.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

and here is the code for the second Activity that should start:

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

    Button settingsBack;
    //Some other layout resources
    final Context context = this;   //Creating reference to this Activity Context

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

        //References to layout resources
        settingsBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsBack);
        //...
        //-----

        //Assigning listeners to Buttons
        settingsBack.setOnClickListener(listenerBack);
        //-----
    }

    //Button listeners definitions
    final OnClickListener listenerBack = new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }

    };    
    //-----

}
```

But when this second Activity should start, I get a NullPointerException at the line, where I assign Listener to the Button. I tried to clean the project in case the R file hasnt generated properly but it didnt solve the problem. The second Activity is declared in manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```

Im sure its just a simple little problem somewhere but I just cant find it :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your layout.help really contains settingsBack button and when you debug your app and you see that settingsBack (Button) is null, I don't see any other reason that some problem with R file or something like that. Maybe try to close/refresh/clean project and/or close Eclipse.

Comment: nandeesh, you just solved it :) I was deriving this code from another already finished Activity and I totaly forgot to change the content view :) I feel so stupid now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time, I copy an activities `onCreate` method to a new activity but forget to change the XML file in the `setContentView`.

I am guessing as the activity is called **Settings**, but the XML is called **help** you might have done the same!?

Comment: Thats exactly what happened to me, I realized when nandeesh asked me for the help.xml code :)

Comment: That and forgetting to add a new activity to the manifest are my two biggest screw-ups when debugging!

Comment: Why do you copy onCreate method? in eclipse you can write "onc" and then press ctrl+space and then enter, and wupti oncreate method generated. :)

Comment: I only copy it when I intend to copy some of the stuff within it. Say my new activity does similar setup routines.